# Retrieving data written inside some textareas

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, textarea

I have to generate a report combining different information from a form.

First of all, I've got to select a substance from here:

```
<input type="checkbox"  class="sostanzeCheck" value="Cocaina" name="sostanza[]" onchange="collectSostanze()"/><span class="testoBianco"> Cocaina </span><br>
<input type="checkbox"  class="sostanzeCheck" value="Crack" name="sostanza[]" onchange="collectSostanze()"/><span class="testoBianco"> Crack </span><br>
<input type="checkbox"  class="sostanzeCheck" value="Marijuana" name="sostanza[]" onchange="collectSostanze()"/><span class="testoBianco"> Marijuana </span><br>
<input type="checkbox"  class="sostanzeCheck" value="Cannabis" name="sostanza[]" onchange="collectSostanze()"/><span class="testoBianco"> Cannabis </span><br>
<input type="checkbox"  class="sostanzeCheck" value="Eroina" name="sostanza[]" onchange="collectSostanze()"/><span class="testoBianco"> Eroina </span><br>
<input type="checkbox"  class="sostanzeCheck" value="Skunk" name="sostanza[]" onchange="collectSostanze()"/><span class="testoBianco"> Skunk </span><br>
<input type="checkbox"  class="sostanzeCheck" value="Sintetiche" name="sostanza[]" onchange="collectSostanze()"/><span class="testoBianco"> Sintetiche </span><br><br>
```

I've already made a function that takes what I select and print it on the console, verifiyng that is correct, which is this one:

```
function collectSostanze(){
      const selectedSostanze = [];
      const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.sostanzeCheck:checked');

      checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
        selectedSostanze.push(checkbox.value);
        console.log("Sostanza: ", selectedSostanze);
      });

     return selectedSostanze;
    }
```

Now, I'm having trouble to collect what I write inside these tre textareas:

```
<div id="bloccoAnalisi" style="display: none;">
    <label>Percentuale di Principio Psicoattivo</label><br>
    <textarea rows="3" cols="80" class="textarea" name="psicoattivo" id="psicoattivo_text" ></textarea><br>
    <label>Grammi</label><br>
    <textarea rows="3" cols="80" class="textarea" name="grammi" id="grammi_text" ></textarea>
    <label>Dosi Medie Singole</label><br> 
    <textarea rows="3" cols="80" class="textarea" name="dosi" id="dosi_text" ></textarea>
 </div><br>
```

These values changes in real time, and what I want to achieve is to generate a report like this:

“I successivi accertamenti tossico-chimici evidenziavano che si trattava di "SUBSTANCE_NAME" con una percentuale media di THC pari al "FIRST TEXTAREA'S VALUE%" e il "FIRST TEXTAREA'S VALUE%" per complessi "SECOND TEXTAREA'S VALUE" grammi sequestrati da cui era possibile ricavare circa "THIRD TEXTAREA'S VALUE" dosi medie singole".

This report has to be added in another textarea, this one:

```
<div id="paragrafiRicostruzione" class="paragrafoFields">
      <h3>Ricostruzione del Fatto</h3>
      <textarea rows="3" cols="80" class="textarea" id="reportTextArea" name="report"></textarea>
</div>
```

Of course I've got to generate different reports based on how many substances I select, appending them one after the other.

I'm working on a Laravel framework and I'm using JS for scripting.

Thanks.

Comment: For the report you could use a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) that updates whenever the form inputs fire an event.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for the keyup event on the form. This event will happen each time the user type something into one of the text areas. And the insert the entire (template) string into the value of the report text area.

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  form.report.value = `I successivi accertamenti tossico-chimici evidenziavano che si trattava di "SUBSTANCE_NAME" con una percentuale media di THC pari al "${form.psicoattivo.value}" e il "${form.psicoattivo.value}" per complessi "${form.grammi.value}" grammi sequestrati da cui era possibile ricavare circa "${form.dosi.value}" dosi medie singole`;
});
```

```css
form>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <div id="bloccoAnalisi">
    <label>Percentuale di Principio Psicoattivo<br>
    <textarea rows="3" cols="80" class="textarea" name="psicoattivo"></textarea></label>
    <label>Grammi<br>
    <textarea rows="3" cols="80" class="textarea" name="grammi"></textarea></label>
    <label>Dosi Medie Singole<br>
    <textarea rows="3" cols="80" class="textarea" name="dosi"></textarea>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div id="paragrafiRicostruzione" class="paragrafoFields">
    <label><h3>Ricostruzione del Fatto</h3>
    <textarea rows="3" cols="80" class="textarea" name="report"></textarea></label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The thing is that I've already have a form and when trying debugging I noticed that it gives me only 1 form.
I've fixed it but now when I write something in the textarea I get this: `formUltimatoConDiv:526 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous>`.